# partial class templates specialization, c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to figure it out, so I have this attempt of specializing a class template:

```
template <class T, int size> class arr{
public:
    arr(T* in):_in(in){};
    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << _in[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
private:
    T* _in;
};
```

I want to create a special template for `arr<char>`. Before I added `int size` as a type parameter it was easy and the class declaretion was `template<> class arr<double>`.

Now I have this `template <> class arr<double,size>` which results in this error:

```
template argument 2 is invalid
```

Any ideas of how to do it? thanks!

Comment: Post the code partial specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <int size> class arr<char, size>
```

Also, you may want to change the type for size to an `unsigned int` or `size_t` (assuming size cannot be negative).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `int size` to the first list- that is, the compiler has no source for `size`- you didn't declare it as a template argument and it's not a constant.

```
template<int size> class arr<double, size> { ... }
```